# If the speed of light is different in two opposite direction, wouldn't we see a bright and dim sky in opposite directions?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, one-way-speed-of-light

There have been asked a lot of questions about the direction dependence of the speed of light. The conclusion is that the speed of light can be different in two directions and we can't measure the speed in one direction. But I have a question still.

If we look at the sky in two opposite directions, wouldn't we see in one direction a brighter sky as in the opposite direction (if we look in the direction for which the speeds differ, say 1/2c in one direction and infinite in the opposite)? All light from all stars in one direction would arrive at the same time, while the light from the other side would take time so less light arrives. Let's assume all stars are uniformly distributed. Of course you can say that observations would contradict this assumption (more light so more stars) but let's assume that our cosmological model predicts uniform matter distribution. By the same token, you could say that in one direction of observation there are less stars but because the speed of light is infinite in that direction it as the same brightness as the opposite direction. But again, let's assume a uniform matter distribution. If the universe is closed wouldn't we observe the Earth itself in one direction, while in the other the Earth isn't visible yet?

Comment: Do you know what theory of special relativity says?

Comment: @MarcBarceló Ýes. You can't know for sure that the speed is the same in two directions. But if we assume the matter in the universe uniformly distributed, wouldn't there be more photons from one direction? The direction in which the speed is smallest? Or would that say matter is not uniformly distributed? (Which you could check by going there).

Comment: You are from a classical Newtonian perspective, but try studying special relativity a bit deeper. Speed of light doesn't depend on direction.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what you may have read somewhere: relativity does not claim that the speed of light can be different in opposite directions, but that in order to *measure* the one-way speed of light you would need a method to synchronize the clocks at the start-  and end-point (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light ).

Comment: @MarcBarceló It's a convention to assume c the same in opposite directions. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: It is not a convention, c is the limit which after Lorentz transformation velocity doesn't change if you move.

Comment: @MarcBarceló It is still a convention.

Comment: "the one-way speed in one direction or the other is undefined (and not simply unknown), unless one can define what is "the same time""

Comment: I am quite sure it isn't a convention. However, maybe you could bring some sources to what you are saying so I can see your point. Mine are the postulates of the special relativity.

Comment: Okay, I have read a bit about what you said and I think I understand it, I didn't know about this convention. However, I think that the Poynting vector (energy flux of light, related to brightness) does not depend on the speed of light as the permittivities and permeabilities cancel out, so this vector may be isotropic, but I am not sure. You could also see: https://spaceaustralia.com/news/one-way-speed-light

Comment: @MarcBarceló Thanks for the link. If the speed of light is different in two directions, wouldn't more of the photons from one direction reach us as from the opposite direction, if the number of stars and their luminosity were the same? If 1000 flashlights on both sides of us shine for a second, wouldn't we see one side all at once and the other side one by one? Or don't we know theyshone at the same time? So we could say that we see all light at the same time because the shone one after another, so all light reaches us at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135320/discussion-between-marc-barcelo-and-felicia).

Answer (score -1):

> All light from all stars in one direction would arrive at the same time, while the light from the other side would take time so less light arrives.

If 10 cars per second start on a trip from New York to San Fransisco at a certain speed, there will still be 10 cars per second arriving in San Fransisco, no matter how fast their (assumed constant) speed is. What changes with speed is the spatial density of cars, not their frequency of arrival. Especially if the guys from New York travel at 70 mph and those from San Francisco travel at 35 mph, the streets in both directions will just be crowded differently, and it is even possible for people to drive in circles between SF and NY, without causing any long-term population loss in either city.

For light, simply substitute the cars by photons and their frequency of arrival by light intensity, in this analogy.

Comment: But if you send a car from all cities to you and they arrive all at the same time you have all cars in your garden at the same time. If it takes them time to arrive the number arriving is less.

Comment: Of course the frequency of the arriving photons won't change but all photons would arrive at the same time. From all stars. Of course after a long time, if all light is radiated constantly and eternally there would be no difference.

Comment: @Felicia: the assumption that all photons of a star are emitted at once at infinite speed is as far from reality as it gets, and moreover, it is mathematically undefined. I am afraid you are fooling yourself by seeking refuge in fuzzy concepts.

Comment: @Felicia No, they would not all arrive at the same time. They would arrive faster, but the spatial distance between them would be correspondingly larger. There will be exactly as many photons arriving per second as were sent out by the source. This follows from the conservation principle alone.

Answer (score -3):

Whether the speed of light is substantially different in opposite directions should be easy to measure: you just have to put a flash light half-way between two detectors and check whether the flash arrives simultaneously at the detectors or not. This is assuming the clocks have been synchronized at the position of the flash light and then moved both to their respective positions. De-synchronization of the clocks due to relativistic time dilation would not be an issue here: if you assume for instance the speed of light is $0.5c$ in one direction and $1.5c$ in the opposite direction, two clocks at a distance of 1m from the light source would register the flash about $3\cdot 10^{-9} sec$ apart, whereas the difference between the time dilation, assuming the synchronized clocks were moved with a speed of let's say $1m/sec$ to their positions, would only be  $$1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(1.5\cdot10^8)^2}} - (1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(4.5\cdot10^8)^2}}) = $$ $$=2\cdot 10^{-17} sec$$. So de-synchronization would be completely negligible (in fact not even be measurable in practice).

Having said this, an anisotropic light speed would anyhow be inconsistent with the Lorentz transformation. The derivation of the latter is based on the assumption of isotropy of the speed of light. Take for instance [Einsteins Simple Derivation of the Lorentz Transformation](https://www.bartleby.com/173/a1.html) and just modify Eqs.(3) and (4) there to make the speed of light $(1+q)\cdot c$ in one direction and $(1-q)\cdot c$ in the other, where $q$ is the anisotropy factor (between 0 and 1, and assumed to be the same in the primed and unprimed reference frame). This yields the equations

$$x'-(1+q)ct'=\lambda(x-(1+q)ct)$$
$$x'+(1-q)ct'=\mu (x+(1-q)ct)$$

If you add and subtract these equations, like Einstein did, you get in this case instead of his Eqs(5)

$$x'=(a-bq)x-bct(1-q^2)$$
$$ct'=(a+bq)ct-bx$$

where  $a=(\lambda +\mu)/2$ and $b=(\lambda -\mu)/2$.

However, these equations are inconsistent with the constraint that the origins of the reference frames must move with the relative velocity $v$ with regard to each other, i.e. we should have
$$x'=0 \Rightarrow x=vt$$
$$x=0 \Rightarrow x'=-vt'$$

It is easy to see from those transformation equations that this is not possible unless the anisotropy factor $q=0$, because in the first case the velocity would be

$$v=\frac{bc(1-q^2)}{a-bq}$$
but in the second
$$v=\frac{bc(1-q^2)}{a+bq}$$

So one one conclude that there can not possibly be *any* linear transformation equation in case of an anisotropic speed of light whilst still assuming the light speed postulate to hold and the relativity principle to apply.

There is no physical reason anyway why you would expect the speed of light to be different in different directions (in a vacuum). And even if it would be different, it would not make any difference for the brightness of the light. The brightness only depends on the number of photons the light source emits per second and on the distance. It is not dependent on the speed of light (an increase/decrease of the speed of the photons would be exactly compensated by a corresponding decrease/increase of the photon density, so each of the detectors would register the same number of photons per second)

Comment: You can't measure which of the two directions has biggest speed. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: If the light reaches you from all stars at the same time you would see more photons then as it took time for photons to reach you. You would receive all photons at once, even of the stars behind the horizon of the universe.

Comment: @Felicia "*You can't measure which of the two directions has biggest speed. That's why I asked the question.*"   Read my answer again, and you'll realize that you can..

Comment: I see what you do. Say you synchronize two clocks before your nose. Place one in front of you and the other behind you. In the same way. Symmetrical. Then shoot a photon to both of them at the same time. Say the photon stops the clocks. You might think different speeds of light stops them at different times so you can infer different speeds. But this is not so. You forget a crucial thing.

Comment: @Felicia "*You forget a crucial thing*" Such as?

Comment: I think you forget if you transport the clocks to the positions in fron of you and the back of you, the time delay due to the twin effect is different in both directions due to the different c's in both directions. So if a clock moves in the direction of infinite c you wont see that clock slow down but the other slows down extra, so the effects will be canceled.

Comment: @Felicia If the speed of light is the same in all directions, both clocks will stop at the same time. If they don't stop at the same time, you know therefore that the speed of light is different. In any case, note that you can ignore the relativistic time dilation effect on the timings here as this is only of second order in $v/c$ and won't even be measurable for pedestrian transport speeds $v$. Any time difference measured will directly reflect the anisotropy of the speed of light ( for an absolute value of the speed of light you would obviuously additionally need a separate two-way timing).

Comment: Okay. You synchronize the two clocks. You set them both at zero before your nose. Then you bring both of them to, say, 300 000 km. away from you. Then you shoot a lightray at them that stops them. You go look at them. You think they show different times if c was different in the directions of both of them?

Comment: Look up Einstein synchronization. If the speed of light is different in different directions, then two clocks moved to different locations do not stay in sync. This is perhaps more obvious if you use two light clocks as your method of timing.

Comment: @Felicia Sure the clocks would show different times if c would be different in the two directions. If the speed would be $0.5c$ in one direction and $1.5c$ in the other (two way speed =$c$), the light would take $3$ times as long to one detector than to the other. But anyway, the derivation of the Lorentz transformation implies the speed to be the same in the two directions. You could not derive it for different speeds (the factor $1-v^2/c^2$ comes from the fact that the speeds are the same ($(1-v/c)*(1+v/c)$))

Comment: @Chris Two synchronized clocks would stay synchronized when moved with identical speed over the same distance if the speed of light is isotropic (and the latter is actually implied by the Lorentz transformation; you could not derive if the speed of light is different in the two directions).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the clocks will stay synchronized if the speed of light is isotropic. That's exactly the point. If the speed of light is non-isotropic, the clocks will drift out of synchronization exactly enough so that they read the same value when the light arrives. Assuming that the speed of light is isotropic is a (very reasonable!) convention. But it is only a convention because there is no way to synchronize two clocks at different locations without relying on conventions.

Comment: @Thomas Deriving a Lorentz transformation by assuming an isotropic speed of light and then using its form to declare that the speed of light must be isotropic is begging the question. The logically sound conclusion to make here with your assumptions is "if the speed of light is anisotropic in a theory, that theory's Lorentz transformation must have a different form."

Comment: This all ties into something deep about special relativity that is the source of many mistakes- simultaneity is relative. From a purely physical standpoint, simultaneity is non-existent, even. Calling two separate events "simultaneous" is purely a matter of convention that is based on our method of synchronizing clocks.

Comment: @Chris "*If the speed of light is non-isotropic, the clocks will drift out of synchronization exactly enough so that they read the same value when the light arrives.*" The de-synchronization due to time dilation would be completely negligible in case the light speed anisotropy is a substantial fraction of the speed of light itself. See my re-edited answer for more

Comment: @Chris "*"if the speed of light is anisotropic in a theory, that theory's Lorentz transformation must have a different form*" There is no transformation possible in case of an anisotropic speed of light whilst keeping up the (one-way) invariance of c and the principle of relativity (see me re-edited answer for more)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135444/discussion-between-chris-and-thomas).